# How to manage a RDS Database including recovery from snapshots in CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-cdk

I am managing an RDS Database in an CDK Project. From time to time it is necasary to recover an old state of the database from snapshot.

To make this possible, I have CDK Context Parameter specifying the Snapshot from which the Database should be recovered. If it is given, the snapshot is bassed to the RDS Construct. This leads to a replacement of the database (which is fine).

Now, if the database has been recovered from snapshot and I do some other update in the CDK Project and want to update the project (which is done via CD Pipeline) I usally start the update without giving any snapshot. This leads to the database to be replaced by an empty one, which is of course not what I want.

To summarize, this is how it currently works:

| Current state of the stack | Deployment Paramter | Result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Not created from snapshot | No snapshot | DB is not replaced |
| Not created from snapshot | snapshot | DB is replaced |
| created from snapshot | No snapshot | DB is replaced |
| created from snapshot | snapshot (same) | DB is not replaced |
| created from snapshot | snapshot (different) | DB is replaced |

This is IMHO not managable.

But what I want is something like this:

| Current state of the stack | Deployment Paramter | Result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Not created from snapshot | No snapshot | DB is not replaced |
| Not created from snapshot | snapshot | DB is replaced |
| created from snapshot | No snapshot | DB is not replaced |
| created from snapshot | snapshot (same) | DB is replaced |
| created from snapshot | snapshot (different) | DB is replaced |

Or, to put it in other words:

- If I specify no snapshot, don't replace the DB
- If I specify a snapshot, repalce the DB

Is this possible? Or is there another good way to manage an RDS Database using CDK?

Comment: have you figured out a good approach for this?

Comment: I would say I found a Jacky approach: store the current snapshot id in SSM Parameter Store and have the cdk read this parameter and set it as the snapshot when no other snapshot should be set. This way the database is not rebuild if the snapshot is changed. I say Jacky because it's not that easy, there where some qwuirks.

Comment: But AWS support did also not have a better idea